# Different animation durations for the same CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to have multiple divs with text that all use the same CSS animation- (blinking), but they should all blink at different rates. Let's say I want the first div to blink once every 2 seconds and the second div to blink once every 4 seconds.

Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code:

```css
.blink {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  /*this is what i'm trying to change*/
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink">hello</div>
<div class="blink">explosion</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using :first-child and :last-child  you can control animation-duration for each of them

```
.blink:first-child {
animation-duration: 0.5s; /*this is what i'm trying to change*/
animation-name: blink;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.blink:last-child {
animation-duration: 1s; /*this is what i'm trying to change*/
animation-name: blink;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.1
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/6xu7yr45/)

or the same

```
.blink{
animation-name: blink;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.blink:first-child {
animation-duration: 0.5s; /*this is what i'm trying to change*/
}
.blink:last-child {
animation-duration: 1s; /*this is what i'm trying to change*/
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.1
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/6xu7yr45/1/)

while you said *(multiple divs)*  you can use  :nth-child(n) for divs like

```
.blink:nth-child(1) {  // for first div
.blink:nth-child(2) {  // for second div
.... so on
```

Comment: I think you can optimize your css.

Comment: Now, the second one is better.

Comment: @alirezasafian . I optimized it while you post your comment :-) ..Thanks

Comment: thanks so much! if you couldn't already tell, i'm a bit new to this :p

Comment: @intrepidspiff never mind .. you're welcome .. Good Luck :-) and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to split the duration into its own class, and use multiple classes in HTML (with `.blink` as the main class):

```css
.blink {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.blink-1s {
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.blink-2s {
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.blink-3s {
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.1
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink blink-1s">one second</div>
<div class="blink blink-2s">two seconds</div>
<div class="blink blink-3s">three seconds</div>
```